# Jest with React Native 57 not working with ES7 syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I've update package.json with

"^.((?!Saga).)*\.js$": "/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js",

However, every component wrote with ES7 syntax stop working, such as

```
export default class Test extends Component {
  state = { test: '' }

  testFunc = () => {}
}
```

Comment: what is the error ? Unexpected token at arrow functions ?

Comment: @KyawSiesein The component cannot render by shallow of enzyme at all. So I got TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined. If I removed everything from es7 the component starts to generate snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by update my .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "presets": ["react-native"]
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue. Can you provide your package.json and any other relevant info? Your suggested change did not resolve the issue for me.

Comment: @AndrewHenderson

(1)I use .babelrc.js instead of .babelrc and add following snippet:
```
let presets = ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"];
let plugins = [];

if (process.env['ENV'] === 'test') {
  presets = ["babel-preset-react-native"];
  plugins = ["jest-hoist"];
}

module.exports = { presets, plugins };
```
(2) add "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
in your devDependencies

(3) Update test script in package.json to
"ENV='test' node_modules/.bin/jest"
The reason to do these is using different preset of babel in different ENV

Answer (score -1):

(1)I use .babelrc.js instead of .babelrc and add following snippet:

```
let presets = ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"];
let plugins = [];

if (process.env['ENV'] === 'test') {
   presets = ["babel-preset-react-native"];
   plugins = ["jest-hoist"];
}

module.exports = { presets, plugins };
```

(2) add "babel-preset-react-native": "^5", in your devDependencies
(3) Update test script in package.json to

`"ENV='test' node_modules/.bin/jest"`

The reason to do these is using different preset of babel in different ENV

Comment: This does not resolve the issue for me. Any component that uses arrow functions returns undefined when using ShallowRenderer.

Comment: The latest version of babel-preset-react-native is 4.0.1 and the project is deprecated in favor of metro-react-native-babel-preset. I'm currently using that.

I should mention that I am using the following in my package.json

  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    }
  }